# Why does adding an extra column of type DATE to the GROUP BY clause cause my SQL query to return extra values?

Tags: sql

Before adding the DATE column, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4
FROM 
    tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    tbl2 ON tbl1.val2 = tbl2.val5
WHERE 
    (tbl2.val6 = @param1)
    AND (tbl1.val3 >= GETDATE() - @param2
    AND tbl1.val3 <= GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4, 
    tbl2.val5, tbl2.val6, tbl2.val7, tbl2.val8, tbl2.val9, tbl2.val10
```

and I get the desired number of rows.

After adding the `DATE` column to both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4, tbl2.date
FROM
    tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    tbl2 ON tbl1.val2 = tbl2.val5
WHERE 
    (tbl2.val6 = @param1)
    AND (tbl1.val3 >= GETDATE() - @param2
    AND tbl1.val3 <= GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4, 
    tbl2.val5, tbl2.val6, tbl2.val7, tbl2.val8, tbl2.val9, 
    tbl2.val10, tbl2.date
```

and I get a ton of extra rows that are the same except for the date.

Why is this happening, and is there any way I can work around this issue?

Comment: You just described basic SQL behavior.  `GROUP BY` rolls up rows that are duplicates, usually based around an aggregate like `SUM`.  If all the dates are different, what do you want them to roll up to?

Comment: The most recent date for a particular value

Comment: Then use max(date) and don't group by it. Also, do not use distinct with group by; it's superfluous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AaronDietz described in his comment to the OP, the date column likely contains many unique values, which will cause the returned sets to be unique for each unique date.

Also in the comments, the OP describes that they want the most recent value of the date. In that case, you can remove the date column from the grouping, and select the `max(tbl2.date)`. Because max() is an aggregate function that returns a single value for the group, there will only be a single value in the date column for each grouping, and thus you will not get all the "extra" rows whose only difference is the date column's value.

Below is an example of the query, with the max(date) added. I've also removed redundant/unused portions of the query. You don't need to use `distinct` since you're already grouping (you can think of distinct as "group by all columns"), nor do you need to group by columns that you are not selecting.

```
SELECT
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4, max(tbl2.date) as date
FROM
    tbl1
INNER JOIN 
    tbl2 ON tbl1.val2 = tbl2.val5
WHERE 
    (tbl2.val6 = @param1)
    AND (tbl1.val3 >= GETDATE() - @param2
    AND tbl1.val3 <= GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    tbl1.val1, tbl2.val1, tbl2.val2, tbl2.val3, tbl2.val4
```

Comment: That query works for the most part. However, it returns 14 more rows than the original, non-date-containing, query. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That seems unlikely; grouping by fewer columns logically cannot produce more rows, as there cannot be more variation (unique combinations of values in a row) in a set that is grouped by columns 1 thru 10, than there can be in a set grouped by 1 thru 20. If you want more targeted help, you're goi to need to put some example results up for us to look at

Comment: @JTM As CaiusJard mentioned, you will only have more rows if there are more unique returned rows. Selecting an aggregated value won't add any more uniqueness (I'm drawing a blank on a better term) to the rows that already would have been returned. My suggestion would be to add an `ORDER BY` clause to both the original query, and this query, and do a diff on the results to see what the new rows are, and what makes them unique. (Eg get the results as a csv value, and run it through a diff program or website)

Comment: After running the query again, I found that I was wrong, and it does, in fact, return the same number of rows as the original. Thanks for the help everyone!